# Как отобрать свой домен у регистратора?

Tags: сеть, dns, домен

Хочу перенести доменное имя от регистратора internetbs.net к адекватному регистратору. Тот просит ввести ЕРР код от текущего регистратора для переноса домена.

Пишу письма в internetbs.net с просьбой предоставить код для переноса. Так они мне уже две недели выносят мозг, "напишите причину", "да у нас лучше", "мы вам сделаем скидку" и т.п.

В итоге , код не дают. Чо делать?

Comment: У вас в каком домене сайт, `.ru`/`.net`/`.com`/?..

Comment: А связаться с тем регистратором, куда хотите перенести домен, пробовали? Могли бы помочь скорее всего...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar По-моему, тут ещё надо указать internetbs на нарушения ими регламента о переносе домена и напомнить, что если они не станут его выполнять, то следом будет жалоба вышестоящему координатору соответствующей TDL. Регистраторы дорожат своей аккредитацией, так что это должно привести их в чувство.

Comment: Только для начала надо скачать этот регламент с сайта координатора и ознакомиться с ним. Во-первых, отсылки на конкретные пункты конкретного документа прибавляют весомость. Во-вторых, надо удостовериться, что вопрошающий выполнил со своей стороны всё, что по документу его касается, чтобы к нему не было претензий.